# Передача значения value в функцию js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

есть задача аяксом динамически выводит html, для этого нужно получать уникальный идентификатор к ссылке `myUrl = "/tarif/user_information/" + idVar;` с цикла php.

Вопрос: 
Как передавать значение `value` кнопки, в функцию `onclick="userInfoTarif();` которая вызывается кликом на эту кнопку, при клике на `<button type="button" value="{{ tarif.id }}" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="userInfoTarif(); return false;">Подробнее</button>`

Если нужно могу предоставить более полный код.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой вопрос следующим методом:

К методу `onclick="userInfoTarif();` добавил this `onclick="userInfoTarif(this);`

в самой же функции `function userInfoTarif(){` добавил elem `function userInfoTarif(elem){`
после чего уже в переменные `var value = elem.value;` или(если брать данные с id) `var id    = elem.id;` получаю данные по клику.

Дальше же просто подставляю одну из этих переменных в нужном мне месте (например в урл, что бы получить его уникальный id)

```
myUrl = "/tarif/user_information/" + id;
```